# OneToOne with the same PrimaryKey and ForeignKey

Tags: java, jpa, orm

**Database**

```
*user_account*
id (PK)
email
password

*user_detail*
id(PK)(FK)
name
city
```

**Entities**

> @Table(name="user_detail")
>   public class UserDetail implementsSerializable{
>
> ```
> @Id private Integer id;
> ...
> @OneToOne
> @JoinColumn(name="id")
> private UserAccount userAccount;
> ```
>
> }

```
@Table(name="user_account")
public class UserAccount implementsSerializable{
    @Id private Integer id;
    @OneToOne(mappedBy="userAccount")
    private UserDetail userDetails;
}
```

**Error**
Exception Description: Multiple writable mappings exist for the field [user_detail.ID].  Only one may be defined as writable, all others must be specified read-only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the ID in `UserAccount` is both a primary key and a foreign key, then you should declare it as a single field and map it appropriately. Like this:

```
@Entity
public class UserAccount implements Serializable {
    @Id
    @OneToOne(mappedBy="userAccount")
    private UserDetail userDetails;
}
```

Or else using `@MapsId`.

However, i suspect that what you really want is a single class spread over two tables:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "user_account")
@SecondaryTable(name = "user_detail")
public class User implements Serializable {
    @Id
    private int id;
    private String email;
    private String password;
    @Column(table = "user_detail")
    private String name;
    @Column(table = "user_detail")
    private String city;
}
```

Comment: Does it make sense to have two tables in the database and just one Entity class?

Comment: Since what you are doing is a composition yes, it does. The real question may be: does it make sense to have two tables?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot have both `@Id private Integer id;` and `@JoinColumn(name="id")`, you must remove one of them: I doubt that you really need a primary key in the details, so just remove the `@Id` line from there.

Comment: You're suggesting using a table with no primary key?

Comment: No, just to remove the annotation and field from the `UserDetail` class. He doesn't need it anyway, since user details are retrieved via the one-to-one mapping.

Comment: Oh, i see. So he'd have an entity class with no ID? That still seems wrong to me.

Comment: Well, clearly his design is flawed to begin with, he probably wanted a composition for no evident reason aside lazy fetching the details; I find it really unlikely that he would ever want to access a user entity from a user details one, so a simple unidirectional one-to-one would have been the right choice. PK id for details, FK in user refercing it, basic stuff.